# Unable to display input[type='number'] value when changed by button

Tags: jquery

I have an input field along with buttons to update the input based on hitting + (Plus) and - (Minus):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.qty-plus', function() {
  $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1, )
})

$(document).on('click', '.qty-minus', function() {
  if ($(this).next().val() > 0)
    $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1, )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter adults">
  <input type="button" value="-" class="qty-minus">
  <input type="number" id="adults" min="1" placeholder="0" class="qty no-bdr" disabled>
  <input type="button" value="+" class="qty-plus">
</div>
```

The function works, however I cannot display the input value using:

```
$('input#adults').keyup(function () {
  $('#displayAdults').text($(this).val());
});
```

I've tried keyup, keydown, I cannot get this to work. I essentially want to show:

There are (number of) adults

Comment: setting value does not trigger events so you have to trigger the event. I am too lazy to find a dupe. `.val(.....).trigger('keyup')`

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the help!

Comment: Instead if keyup, use on change event. $('input#adults').on('change', function() {
  $('#displayAdults').text($(this).val());
});

Comment: @user341143 that's still not fired automatically though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically changing the value of an `input` does not raise an event. If you want that behaviour you need to do it manually using `trigger()`. I would suggest using the `change` event for this.

Also note that you can DRY up your code by using a common function to change the value along with `data` attributes to hold the value to change by, and also by using `siblings()` to get the related `input` from the buttons. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.qty-change', function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.siblings('input').val(function(i, v) {
    return parseInt(v) + $el.data('increment');
  }).trigger('change');
})

$('input#adults').on('change', function() {
  $('#displayAdults').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter adults">
  <button type="button" class="qty-change" data-increment="-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="adults" min="1" placeholder="0" class="qty no-bdr" value="0" disabled>
  <button type="button" class="qty-change" data-increment="1">+</button>
</div>

<div id="displayAdults"></div>
```

Comment: He's right. I've utilized it in this way: 
`let target = $(e.target);`
`$($('.item_quantity')[0]).val(target.val())`